# CKeditor is not working with jquery > 1.8

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, navigation, javascript

I'm trying to get superfish accordion working on my pages. I have to have my jquery_update set to 1.9 or greater to get that function working.

But when I do I lose ckeditor on the comment fields for things like forums and such. I'm not sure what to do to resolve this problem.

Currently running Drupal 7.53

[CKEditor for Drupal module 7.x-1.17](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor)

[Superfish menu module 7.x-2.0](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish)

Comment: To improve your question, could you provide a link to the Drupal module or library you're using for the superfish accordion functionality, along with which version of Drupal you're using?

Comment: According to the Superfish module documentation it only requires JQuery 1.6.1 or higher. Is there a specific reason you're using jQuery 1.8 or 1.9?

Comment: The specific reason is that when I try to use any version lower then 1.9 the accordion display doesn't kick on on the smaller screen sizes. I'm not sure why, or how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this may have been the cause.

I use AdaptiveTheme for my base theme on everything really. Right now the default theme makes use of a FooTheme created with a Corolla base. I had menu setting in the theme turned on and I think it was interfering with the Superfish menu.

If you are using Superfish then turn off all mobile menu options in AdaptiveTheme.